# Insert into não retorna

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:
[image: tabelas relacionadas]

Query com Insert

```
public function CadastrarArquivos($pdo, $arq_nome, $a_areaid, $u_userid){
        $ins = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO arq_arquivos(arq_nome, a_area_a_areaid, u_usuarios_u_useid) VALUES(:arq_nome, :a_areaid, :u_userid)"
            );
        $ins->bindParam(":arq_nome",$arq_nome);
        $ins->bindParam(":a_areaid",$a_areaid);
        $ins->bindParam(":u_userid",$u_userid);
```

```
    $obj = $ins->execute();

    return ($obj) ? $obj : false;<code>
```

//Função php para cadastrar

```
function cadastrarArquivo($app){
```

`$param = array("titulo"=>$app->site_titulo, 
                       "pagina" => "formarquivos",
                       "dados" => array(
                            "tituloform" => "Cadastrar novo Arquivo",
                            "action"=>"execCadastrarArquivo",
                            "arq_arqid"=>"",                                
                            "arq_nome"=>"",
                            "labelbtnsubmit"=>"Cadastrar"

                        )
                       );

        $app->loadView("Admin",$param);
    }

    function execCadastrarArquivo($app){
        $admin = $app->loadModel("Admin");


        $arq_nome = ($_POST["arq_nome"]);
        $a_areaid = 1;   /*marque 1 para selecionar uma area já existente de teste.*/
        $u_userid = $_SESSION["u_userid"];

        $obj = $admin->CadastrarArquivos($app->conexao, $arq_nome, $a_areaid,  $u_userid);

        if($obj) {
            $mensagem = "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!";
        } else {
            $mensagem = "Cadastro falhou!";
        }

        $this->listarareainicial($app,$admin,$mensagem);
    }<code>`

//Dessa forma não está dando erro algum, porem não cadastra no banco.

formulário html

`<form method="POST" action="index.php?m=admin&c=minhaarea&a=<?=$tpl["dados"]["action"]?>">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
                <strong>Nome do arquivo:</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" name="arq_nome" class="col-xs-12 form-control" 
                value="<?=$tpl["dados"]["arq_nome"]?>" autofocus required />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row marginTop">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="submit" value="<?=$tpl["dados"]["labelbtnsubmit"]?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$tpl["dados"]["arq_arqid"]?>" name="arq_arqid" />
</form>`

Comment: Não que não possa funcionar assim, mas seria legal simplificar o código. Se você tem `function CadastrarArquivos`, `function cadastrarArquivo` e `function execCadastrarArquivo`, algo não parece muito bom no jeito de organizar o código.

Comment: Então a function CadastrararquivoS fica separado, junto somente com as query, já a CadastrarArquivo retorna para o usuario uma pagina com o form para ele digitar, e para enviar tem um botão que chama a function execCadastrararquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema parece ser na parte `$ins->bindParam(":a_areaid",$a_areaid);`.
Coloque o parâmetro `PDO::PARAM_INT`, após o `$a_areaid` dessa maneira:

```
$ins->bindParam(":a_areaid",$a_areaid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

use esse parâmetro quando for passar um valor int para o banco de dados.

Mais informações neste link:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Dei uma lida no link, entendi, fiz o teste mas mesmo assim não foi, eu coloquei o formulário html na minha pergunta acima.

Comment: Notei o seguinte, se eu vou no banco e faço um insert, funciona normal, agora pelo php não vai, MAS percebi que após eu tentar cadastrar pelo php e ele não cadastrar, vou no banco e o ID ele gera um na sequencia, como se o do php tivesse funcionado. Não entendo como é possível.

Comment: O atributo action pode estar dando conflito nas aspas duplas. Está escrito assim: <form method="POST" action="index.php?m=admin&c=minhaarea&a=<?=$tpl["dados"]["action"]?>"> . Retire as aspas de dados e action, ou coloque aspas simples em volta.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar tirando a ligação entre as tabelas arq_arquivos com a a_area, vou repensar melhor sobre as duas tabelas, comentarei caso veja algum problema mais especifico para que outros possam aproveitar meu tópico, grato a todos.